# EJB : module and beans, project design

Tags: netbeans, ejb-3.0, java-ee-6

This might be a noob question but since I am starting a project from scratch, I am trying to avoid wrong choices for my project design.

Environment (constraints) : JEE6, EJB 3, JPA, Glassfish 3, Maven, Netbeans 7.

I have a User service (register, login, remove, update, etc.)
I have a Bank service (same idea...)
I have a BankAccount service which links User and Bank.
I have an Operation service (add, remove, etc.)

I would like to create one EJB per service. But, some of the services share (JPA) entities. Does it mean that I MUST put them all in one EJB module ? If I must, does it mean that I have to move the whole module when I want to distribute only one EJB service ?

Basically, I have domain classes (User, Bank...) and service classes (UserService, BankService...). Services would be in EJB. EJB would be independent as much as possible. 
Where should I put my domain classes ? In a library shared by EJBs ? In one EJB module ? 
Usually how do you organize your classes ? (domain, services...)

Also, do you know some good sites or books about JEE6 project design ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question about sites and books about EE 6.

I would recommend that you have a look at [Adam Bien's website](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/) and [Antonio Goncalves website](http://antoniogoncalves.org/).

Both have written great books. Adam has written "Real World Java EE Patterns--Rethinking Best Practices" and Antonio "Beginning Java EE 6 with Glassfish 3" he also brought out a book on EE 7